# JTable functionality

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I'm creating an basic invoice page and where I want to enter product details I am going to have a JTable with four columns, Quantity, Description, unit cost and Total

[image: JTable]

When I am finishing entering the details in the form I want then to click save and the Details will automatically update to the database.

Can some one please tell me the best way of going about this process.  Will an ordinary `JTable` do this or is there another type table would be more suitable?

Comment: *"Will an ordinary `JTable` do this.."*  Sure.  Or rather, it will do part of what you want.  You will have to write the code to bind the table to the DB, but then, that's why they pay us the 'big bucks'.  ;)

Comment: You should probably also consider using JPA/Hibernate. This would allow you to have a custome `TableModel` directly bound to objecs. To save the whole table, all you would have to do is `entityManager.persist()`

Comment: I'm not too worried about the coding, just the best approach, I've seen vectors been used in some places.

Comment: Best approach is pretty dependent on the context of the problem.  How often are these rows being saved, how many users do you have, etc. etc.  Using a simple POJO entity to contain the values then persist the data through JPA / Hibernate would be the easiest solution as @GuillaumePolet stated, not sure what you mean by the vectors being used, vectors are being used as just a way of storing the data between the view and the service, I'm guessing, this doesn't matter as much imo.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a custom `TableModel` and JPA/Hibernate.

You will find below a very basic example of this (code needs to be splitted of course).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TestSwingTableJPA {

    private JPATableModel tableModel;
    private JFrame frame;

    private class JPATableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<TestSwingTableJPA.Item>();

        private EntityManager entityManager;

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Item item = getValueAt(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return item.getQuantity();
            case 1:
                return item.getDescription();
            case 2:
                return item.getCostPerUnit();
            case 3:
                if (item.getQuantity() != null && item.getCostPerUnit() != null) {
                    return item.getCostPerUnit().multiply(item.getQuantity());
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            default:
                break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Item item = getValueAt(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                item.setQuantity((BigDecimal) aValue);
                fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, 3); // Total may also have changed
                break;
            case 1:
                item.setDescription((String) aValue);
                break;
            case 2:
                item.setCostPerUnit((BigDecimal) aValue);
                fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, 3); // Total may also have changed
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                return BigDecimal.class;
            case 1:
                return String.class;
            }
            return Object.class;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return "Quantity";
            case 1:
                return "Description";
            case 2:
                return "Cost Per Unit";
            case 3:
                return "Total";
            default:
                break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return columnIndex == 0 || columnIndex == 1 || columnIndex == 2;
        }

        private Item getValueAt(int row) {
            return items.get(row);
        }

        public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
            this.items = items;
            fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        public void addItem(Item item) {
            getEntityManager().persist(item);
            this.items.add(item);
            fireTableRowsInserted(this.items.size() - 1, this.items.size() - 1);
        }

        public List<Item> reload() {
            return getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("selectAllItems", Item.class).getResultList();
        }

        public void save() {
            getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
            getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
        }

        public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
            if (entityManager == null) {
                // You need to configure your persistence unit in META-INF/persistence.xml
                EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPersistenceUnit");
                entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
            }
            return entityManager;
        }

    }

    public TestSwingTableJPA() {
    }

    @Entity(name = "Item")
    @NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "selectAllItems", query = "select item from Item as item") })
    public static class Item {

        private Long id;

        private BigDecimal quantity;
        private String description;
        private BigDecimal costPerUnit;

        public BigDecimal getQuantity() {
            return quantity;
        }

        public void setQuantity(BigDecimal quantity) {
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public BigDecimal getCostPerUnit() {
            return costPerUnit;
        }

        public void setCostPerUnit(BigDecimal costPerUnit) {
            this.costPerUnit = costPerUnit;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    protected void initUI() {
        frame = new JFrame(TestSwingTableJPA.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JTable table = new JTable(tableModel = new JPATableModel());
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint()) == -1) {
                    tableModel.addItem(new Item());
                }
            }
        });
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 5));
        JButton save = new JButton("Save");
        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                save();
            }
        });
        JButton reload = new JButton("Reload");
        reload.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                reload();
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(save);
        buttonPanel.add(reload);
        panel.add(buttonPanel);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        reload();
    }

    protected void save() {
        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame);
        JProgressBar progress = new JProgressBar();
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.add(progress);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
        SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                tableModel.save();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                dialog.dispose();
            }

        };
        worker.execute();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected void reload() {
        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame);
        JProgressBar progress = new JProgressBar();
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.add(progress);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
        SwingWorker<List<Item>, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<List<Item>, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected List<Item> doInBackground() throws Exception {
                return tableModel.reload();
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                try {
                    tableModel.setItems(get());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Could not fetch items from database", "Error while loading items",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } finally {
                    dialog.dispose();
                }
            }

        };
        worker.execute();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final TestSwingTableJPA testSwingTableJPA = new TestSwingTableJPA();
                testSwingTableJPA.initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit">

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test"/>


            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

All you need is to set up a local postgresql database "test" on port 5432 with a user test (pwd test).

One of the down-side of this is if you loose the connection to the database. I am not sure on how it will behave, but you may need to recreate a new EntityManager and therefore loose all unsaved changes. I am not a JPA/Hibernate expert.

If you use Maven, here are the dependencies I have used:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
```